# Why jobs are not waiting in waiting queue in bull?

Tags: node.js, bull.js

I am using bull as a job queue. I have set this rate limit with the queue.

```
const opts = {
    limiter: {
        max: 1,
        duration: 100,
        bounceBack: false
    }
};

let queue = new Queue('FetchQueue', opts);
```

My understanding of `bounceBack: false` is that it put the job in the delayed queue or waiting queue if it can't be processed immediately. But I am getting this error intermittently.

```
StatusCodeError: 403 - {"error":{"code":403,"message":"User Rate Limit Exceeded","errors":[{"message":"User Rate Limit Exceeded","domain":"usageLimits","reason":"userRateLimitExceeded"}]}}
```

What is the correct setting for bounceBack to make jobs wait in the job queue?

Comment: see this link you can use `bounceBack: true`: https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/pull/1096/files

Comment: Using that option simply discards the job. It is not added to the waiting queue